# retrive the last match case or list with regular expression and than work with it

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex

my issue is that I'll download html page content to string with

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
string webData = wc.DownloadString("http://prices.shufersal.co.il/");
```

and trying to retrive the last number of page from the navigation menu

```
<a data-swhglnk=\"true\" href=\"/?page=2\">2</a>
```

so at the end I'll want want to find the last data-swhglnk and retrive from it the last page.
I try

```
Regex.Match(webData, @"swhglnk", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

I would be happy to understand the right approch to issues like this

Comment: Use htmlagility pack.

Comment: When I come back home I'll show how to use the HTML parser if no one does it before. The problem with the regex is that it will be inefficient and unsafe. Although in C# it is possible to write a working regex for it, it is greatly discouraged to use regex to get values from HTML code and such an answer is usually downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're about to parse HTML and find some information in it, you should use method more reliable than regex, i.e:

-HtmlAgilityPack https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

-csQuery https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

and operate on objects, not strings.

*Update*

If you decide to use HtmlAgilityPack, you will have to write code like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webData);
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@data-swhglnk]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute data = node.Attributes["data-swhglnk"];
    //do your processing here
}
```